# Live Fedora 22 on flash drive fails to boot

Tags: bootable

I downloaded the fedora 22 iso, and used WindowsXP-Rufus to make a flash drive bootable and put the iso onto the flash drive.  Unclear if relevant - I had to manually download ldlinux.bss and ldlinux.sys before rufus would work on this iso.  Unclear if relevant - used 2 gb flash drive, with 1.4 gb iso, leaving 600mb free on flash drive.

Attempting to boot from flashdrive onto my newly built pc (16 gb memory, 64 bit mobo), I got the following messages:

Mounting Configuration File System

[ok] Mounted Config File System

[ok] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen

[ok] Reached Target Paths

[ok] Reached Target Basic System

[187.669259] dracut - initqwue[402]: Warning: Could not boot

[187.692088] dracut - initqwue[402]: Warning: 
/dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-Live-WS-x86_64-21-5 does not exist

[187.692762] dracut - initqwue[402]: Warning:
/dev/mapper/live-rw does not exist

I verified that rufus did make the flash drive's volume label = 
Fedora-Live-WS-x86_64-21-5

Following the warning messages, the boot process suggested that I exit out of the "current shell", which I did.  I (apparently) was then placed in terminal mode.

Request help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on linux, and not on fedora, you could use dd (live usb creator is using it in some case), your usb key will be totaly overwritten so back up your data.

the command is :

```
mount
```

see where your usb key is mounted (let say hdb2)

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb2

sudo dd if=<fedora iso file> of=/dev/sdb2 bs=4M
```

- "if" is for input file,
- "of" is for output file,
- "bs" is for blocksize

No progress is shown after executing the `dd` command. Wait to get the prompt again.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue when trying to instal F22 in my laptop.
It appears that is a USB write method problem that happens with all software except when writing the ISO image with liveusb-creator.

Download it from https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/ and it will run like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for the insight Juan.  Unfortunately, I am currently running Lubuntu, whose Start Up Disk Creator won't recognize the Fedora 22 iso.  Also, my Lubuntu apt-get attempt to install liveusb-creator has failed.  Does anyone know how to install liveusb-creator (or any reliable and versatile iso to flashdrive software) in Lubuntu, so that I can create a Fedora 22 bootable flash drive from within Lubuntu?

Comment: Ok, in that case you can download the sources, compile and run: # wget https://fedorahosted.org/releases/l/i/liveusb-creator/liveusb-creator-3.13.2.tar.bz2 ; tar xvj liveusb-creator-3.13.2.tar.bz2 ; cd liveusb-creator-3.13.2; make && make install ;      Then you run the application and write your Fedora image.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but the kernel was not able to load and/or the boot loader said there was no bootable image available.

It turned out the ISO image I wrote onto the flash drive was short by about 100 MB, no doubt due to an unsupervised and incomplete download.  It had been so long since I had a download error that I stopped verifying the sha256sum years ago.

The fix was simple:  download the .iso again and check the sha256 value against the posted correct value.  Reflash and boot.